# A word for saying "waiting with good anticipation"?

Tags: single-word-requests

What word would you choose for "waiting" for something good?

As a header for a photo, I want to say:

> "Last days of summer. Waiting for the winter."

But it should be clear that I like winters and waiting for it with good excitement and want it to come already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @HotLicks proposed in the comment and disappeared I will accept it:

> **Looking forward** to winter.

Answer (score 1):

I would use

> Impatient

It conveys your excitement, and that it is taking too long to arrive. It also does so without implying it may not happen (as per your response to *wishing*).

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

> Wishing for Winter

Paraphrased from [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/wish):

> wanting or desiring something

Comment: I'm not `wishing` because it will sure come. I'm just waiting for it.

Comment: @Sanich But you could be wishing it was here already.

Answer (score -2):

You could use the word, "Sanguine", it's an adjective

Positively optimistic, hopeful or confident.